# How to get parsed request data from XHR

Tags: javascript, python, flask, xmlhttprequest

I am sending a POST request to a Flask server from javascript using the following code:

```
var form = document.getElementById('addbug');
fd = new FormData(form);

function senddata() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log("Response Received");
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', '/addbug');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','binary/octet-stream');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-transfer-encoding','binary');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
    fd.append('bug_summary',document.getElementById('bug_summary').value);
    fd.append('csrf_token',document.getElementById('csrf_token').value);
    xhr.send(fd);
    return false;
}
```

When I read this data in the python script I face two issues:

1. The variable request.form['addbug'] is not populated - i.e. is empty. The following command:

   ```
   print(str(request.form))
   ```

   returns
       ImmutableMultiDict([])
2. The request body which I can only access using the request.get_data function does have data but is formatted like:

   ```
   ------WebKitFormBoundaryG4ehfDXtXEwIsktm
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bug_summary"

   test bug
   ------WebKitFormBoundaryG4ehfDXtXEwIsktm
   ```

How can I get the data from the request body in the cleanest way? The best option would have been to use the request.form entry, but it seems that because I am using the XMLHttpRequest option instead of the flask standard form submission I cannot use that. Are there any good parsing options for reading request form data, or do I need to write the parsing code myself?

Comment: console.log() the form data right before it gets sent

Comment: @reptilicus I can do that, but can you elaborate what purpose would it serve? I can read the request data in the python code just fine (see the last sample) but I am struggling with how to parse that data into a well-formatted data structure (like dict)

Comment: that `ImmutableMultiDict` behaves much as a standard `dict`. Just do `data = request.form["bug_summary"]`